# How to do validation on a TextBox in Silverlight, end-to-end?

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, validation, xaml, binding

I'm trying to add Validation to a Silverlight 3.0 TextBox but cannot seem to find and example which is complete, and not missing functionality that makes it work, I have this property:

```
    ''' <summary>Tag</summary>
    ''' <value>String</value>
    ''' <returns>String</returns>
    ''' <remarks>Contains Validation</remarks>
    Public Property Tag() As String
        Get
            Return _Tag
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            If Value.Length < 1 Or Value.Length > 20 Then
                Throw New Exception("Must be between 1 and 20 characters")
            End If
            _Tag = Value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Tag")
        End Set
    End Property
```

This is in a class which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged class, I have this textbox:

```
<TextBox Name="txtTag" Text="{Binding Path=Tag, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>
```

In my XAML, what do I need to do to have this use Validation correctly - that is show the "red" tooltip to show the error message, my code just throws the exception, and does not display the message at or work correctly.
I have found examples online, but all seem to miss out a critical piece of functionality that makes this work - what is the reason for this? I just want to do simple validation in Silverlight, I know it is possible so if anyone knows an end-to-end solution to make this work then please post it here.
This is an open-source project so I won't be keeping the solution to myself - so it may help others as this is quite a useful feature - if not poorly explained for me to get it to work.

---

**Edit**

Just though I would add that if possible can the Error condition of a Textbox be invoked without using an exception - i.e I do my own validation and then call the error state on the TextBox and show the custom error message, this would be an acceptable alternative. 
I have the Tag property in a Class, I'm guessing when the exception is thrown it cannot be caught by the TextBox as it is not in the MainPage class, but there is so little documentation, a couple of good examples with no code I'm not sure how this is supposed to work.
Hopefully there is a solution that does not involve re-implementing the error state with coloured borders and custom tooltips, as the functionality is there - I just need to use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. You can add a `<ValidationSummary/>` to the panel containing the `TextBox` to see the validation errors. You can also subscribe to the `TextBox.BindingValidationError` event to see when validation errors occur as in the data-binding. If you debug your code you should be able to first see the exception being thrown and then the event being raised.

Unfortunately you cannot "manually" add validation errors to the `TextBox`. To get a validation error you will have to throw an exception in the a data-bound property like you do. If you want really fine-grained control of when the validation error occurs you can manually update the binding expression.

Instead of performing your validation in code you can use the attributes in namepace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`. For instance, to validate on string length you can use the `StringLength` attribute:

```
<StringLength(20, MinimumLength:=1>
Public Property Tag() As String
    Get
        ....
```

Comment: I had a feeling that the exception-throw-catch method was the way of doing this, I just need to move my Property from the Class to the MainPage class, so the exception is caught by the bound-property correctly, if this works then I have got it in the wrong place!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this blog on Silverlight Data Binding/Validation:

[Data Binding - Data Validation](http://jesseliberty.com/2008/10/13/data-binding-%E2%80%93-data-validation/)

...it looks like you're missing the Error Event Handler (what does the work when the Exception is thrown). Check the link to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: I knew I was missing something, I found a few examples online - none of these had that part - assumed prior knowledge I guess - will try this!